# Difference between PCDATA and CDATA in DTD

Tags: xml, dtd

What is the difference between `#PCDATA` and `#CDATA` in **DTD**?

Comment: possible duplicate of [what actually is PCDATA and CDATA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857876/what-actually-is-pcdata-and-cdata)

Comment: The names of the keywords used in XML DTDs are `#PCDATA` and `CDATA`. There is no `PCDATA` keyword and no  `#CDATA`.

Comment: In addition to the accepted answer you should read https://stackoverflow.com/a/918462/2013911 because it explains the difference between CDATA attribute type and <![CDATA[]]> marked sections.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

PCDATA - Parsed Character Data

XML parsers normally parse all the text in an XML document.

CDATA - (Unparsed) Character Data

The term CDATA is used about text data that should not be parsed by the XML parser.

Characters like "<" and "&" are illegal in XML elements.

Answer (score 88):

- `PCDATA` is text that will be parsed by a parser. Tags inside the text
  will be treated as markup and entities will be expanded.
- `CDATA` is text that will *not* be parsed by a parser. Tags inside the text will
  *not* be treated as markup and entities will not be expanded.

By default, everything is `PCDATA`. In the following example, ignoring the root, `<bar>` will be parsed, and it'll have no content, but one child.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo>
<bar><test>content!</test></bar>
</foo>
```

When we want to specify that an element will only contain text, and no child elements, we use the keyword `PCDATA`, because this keyword specifies that the element must contain parsable character data – that is , any text except the characters less-than (`<`) , greater-than (`>`) , ampersand (`&`), quote(`'`) and double quote (`"`).

In the next example, `<bar>` contains `CDATA`. Its content will not be parsed and is thus `<test>content!</test>`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo>
<bar><![CDATA[<test>content!</test>]]></bar>
</foo>
```

There are several content models in SGML. The `#PCDATA` content model says that an element may contain plain text. The "parsed" part of it means that markup (including PIs, comments and SGML directives) in it is parsed instead of displayed as raw text. It also means that entity references are replaced.

Another type of content model allowing plain text contents is `CDATA`. In XML, the element content model may not implicitly be set to `CDATA`, but in SGML, it means that markup and entity references are ignored in the contents of the element. In attributes of `CDATA` type however, entity references are replaced.

In XML, `#PCDATA` is the only plain text content model. You use it if you at all want to allow text contents in the element. The `CDATA` content model may be used explicitly through the `CDATA` block markup in `#PCDATA`, but element contents may not be defined as `CDATA` per default.

In a DTD, the type of an attribute that contains text must be `CDATA`. The `CDATA` keyword in an attribute declaration has a different meaning than the `CDATA` section in an XML document. In a `CDATA` section all characters are legal (including `<`,`>`,`&`,`'` and `"` characters), except the `]]>` end tag.

`#PCDATA` is not appropriate for the type of an attribute. It is used for the type of "leaf" text.

`#PCDATA` is prepended by a hash in the content model to distinguish this keyword from an element named `PCDATA` (which would be perfectly legal).

Comment: Great answer, except for the last sentence. `#` is not a hashtag. Only a tag preceded by this symbol is a hashtag. The symbol itself has [many names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign#Other_names_in_English), including "number sign", "pound sign" (mostly Canada & US), or just "hash" (hence the name 'hashtag').

Comment: #justhadtogetthatoffmychest

Comment: I do not agree that the # in front of `#PCDATA` is there for historical reasons. It is there because in a DTD, an element could also contain an element named `PCDATA`, which must be possible, and which would look like `<!ELEMENT foo (PCDATA)>`.

Comment: Quote and double-quote are perfectly legal in PCDATA content.  And ampersand may appear, but (in XML) only as an entity introducer.

Answer (score 16):

**PCDATA – parsed character data.** It parses all the data in an XML document.

Example:

```xml
<family>
    <mother>mom</mother>
    <father>dad</father>
</family>
```

Here, the `<family>` element contains 2 more elements: **`<mother>`** and **`<father>`**. So it parses further to get the text of mother and father to give the text value of family as **“mom dad”**

**CDATA – unparsed character Data.** This is the data that should not be parsed further in an xml document.

```xml
<family>
    <![CDATA[ 
       <mother>mom</mother>
       <father>dad</father>
    ]]>
</family>
```

Here, the text value of family will be `<mother>mom</mother><father>dad</father>`.

Answer (score 12):

[From here](http://lists.xml.org/archives/xml-dev/199906/msg00737.html) ([Google is your friend](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=pcdata+vs+cdata)):

> In a DTD, PCDATA and CDATA are used to
>   assert something about the allowable
>   content of elements and attributes,
>   respectively. In an element's content
>   model, #PCDATA says that the element
>   contains (may contain) "any old text."
>   (With exceptions as noted below.) In
>   an attribute's declaration, CDATA is
>   one sort of constraint you can put on
>   the attribute's allowable values
>   (other sorts, all mutually exclusive,
>   include ID, IDREF, and NMTOKEN). An
>   attribute whose allowable values are
>   CDATA can (like PCDATA in an element)
>   contain "any old text."
>
> A potentially really confusing issue
>   is that there's *another* "CDATA,"
>   also referred to as marked sections. A
>   marked section is a portion of element
>   (#PCDATA) content delimited with
>   special strings:  to close it. If you
>   remember that PCDATA is "parsed
>   character data," a CDATA section is
>   literally the same thing, without the
>   "parsed." Parsers transmit the content
>   of a marked section to downstream
>   applications without hiccupping every
>   time they encounter special characters
>   like < and &. This is useful when
>   you're coding a document that contains
>   lots of those special characters (like
>   scripts and code fragments); it's
>   easier on data entry, and easier on
>   reading, than the corresponding entity
>   reference.
>
> So you can infer that the exception to
>   the "any old text" rule is that PCDATA
>   cannot include any of these unescaped
>   special characters, UNLESS they fall
>   within the scope of a CDATA marked
>   section.

Answer (score 4):

The very main difference between PCDATA and CDATA is

PCDATA - Basically used for ELEMENTS while

CDATA - Used for Attributes of XML i.e ATTLIST

Answer (score 0):

CDATA (**C**haracter **DATA**): It is similarly to a comment but it is part of document. i.e. CDATA is a data, it is part of the document but the data can not  parsed in XML.
**Note:** XML comment omits while parsing an XML but CDATA shows as it is.

PCDATA (**P**arsed **C**haracter **DATA**) :By default, everything is PCDATA. PCDATA is a data, it can be parsed in XML.

Answer (score 0):

## PCDATA

PCDATA: (Parsed Character Data): XML parsers are used to parse all the text in an XML document. PCDATA stands for Parsed Character data. PCDATA is the text that will be parsed by a parser. Tags inside the PCDATA will be treated as markup and entities will be expanded.

In other words you can say that a parsed character data means the XML parser examine the data and ensure that it doesn't content entity if it contains that will be replaced.

Let's take an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<!DOCTYPE employee SYSTEM "employee.dtd">  
<employee>  
  <firstname>vimal</firstname>  
  <lastname>jaiswal</lastname>  
  <email>vimal@javatpoint.com</email>  
</employee>
```

In the above example, the employee element contains 3 more elements 'firstname', 'lastname', and 'email', so it parses further to get the data/text of firstname, lastname and email to give the value of employee as:

```
vimal jaiswal vimal@javatpoint.com
```

## CDATA

CDATA: (Unparsed Character data): CDATA contains the text which is not parsed further in an XML document. Tags inside the CDATA text are not treated as markup and entities will not be expanded.

Let's take an example for CDATA:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<!DOCTYPE employee SYSTEM "employee.dtd">  
<employee>  
<![CDATA[  
  <firstname>vimal</firstname> 
  <lastname>jaiswal</lastname> 
  <email>vimal@javatpoint.com</email> 
]]>   
</employee>
```

In the above CDATA example, CDATA is used just after the element employee to make the data/text unparsed, so it will give the value of employee:

```
<firstname>vimal</firstname><lastname>jaiswal</lastname><email>vimal@javatpoint.com</email>
```